# Store Radio Button Value to Database in PHP Codeigniter in Perfex CRM

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, radio-button

I'm attempting to save the radio button value to the database in Perfex CRM, and I've successfully saved the value of the select dropdown using the code below.

```
                        $accessability = [
                            0 => ["id" => "Yes", "name" => _l("Yes")],
                            1 => ["id" => "No", "name" => _l("No")],
                            2 => ["id" => "Not Applicable", "name" => _l("Not Applicable")]
                        ];
                        $value = isset($accessability)
                            ? $disscussion->accessability
                            : "";
                        echo render_select(
                            "accessability",
                            $accessability,
                            ["id", "name"],
                            "ACCESSABILITY TO PROPERTY WAS CLEAR",
                            $value
                        );
                        ?>
```

Here I am trying to store the radio button value to database.

```
                     <div class="col-md-12">                           
                        <div class="mtop10">
                           <span>ACCESSABILITY TO PROPERTY WAS CLEAR</span>

                            <div class="radio radio-primary radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" value="1" id="1"  name="Yes" data-text="Yes" <?php if(isset($accessability)  ? $disscussion->accessability : ""; ?>>
                              <label for="1">Yes</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="radio radio-primary radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" value="1" id="2"  name="No" data-text="Yes" <?php if(isset($accessability)  ? $disscussion->accessability : ""; ?>>
                              <label for="2">No</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Iam New to Codeignitor Please Help

Answer (score 0):

```
                     <!-- Accessibility -->
                     <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="accessibility">Accessibility</label><br>
                            <div class="radio radio-primary radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="accessibility" <?php if(isset($accessability) && $disscussion->accessability == 0){echo ' checked';}?> value="Yes" id="yes">
                                <label for="yes">Yes</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio radio-primary radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="accessibility" <?php if(isset($accessability) && $disscussion->accessability == 1){echo ' checked';}?> value="No" id="no">
                                <label for="no">No</label>
                            </div>
                     </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).